# non-conformable arrays ERROR when pooling multiple imputation datasets Joint Modelling

Tags: r

I am a new R user and struggeling.

I imported 3 separate multiple imputation datasets into R and conducted 3 separate LMM + Cox-PH analyses. Consequently I want to pool the results to obtain pooled estimates using the following script.

#### Pooled Mixed model 1

```
JMModel1_MMSE_fleisch_fu <- list(fit.JM1, fit.JM2, fit.JM3)
```

> ## 'JMModel1_MMSE_fleisch_fu ' is a list with the fitted joint models

```
n <- (length(JMModel1_MMSE_fleisch_fu))

W <- Reduce("+", lapply(JMModel1_MMSE_fleisch_fu, vcov)) / n

B <- var(t(sapply(JMModel1_MMSE_fleisch_fu,fixef, process = "Event"))) # or process = "Event"

V <- W + ((n + 1) / n) * B
```

> #### Error non-conformable arrays

```
betas <- rowMeans(sapply(JMModel1_MMSE_fleisch_fu, fixef, process = "Longitudinal")) # or process = "Event"

ses <- sqrt(diag(V))

pvals <- pchisq((betas/ses)^2, 1, lower.tail = FALSE)

round(cbind("Value" = betas, "Std.Err" = sqrt(diag(V)), "p-value" = pvals), 4)
```

#

However, when I run the "V" command I receive an error. 
"W" is a matrix 21/21
"B" is a matrix 8/8

My question is, do you know what to do to make the formula running?

I tried to run the script for LMM alone. 
"W" is a matrix 6/6
"B" is a matrix 8/8
and it worked.

Thank you for your time!

Best wishes,
Debora